# 'jquery-rails' and 'jquery-ui-rails' can they be managed under one project?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails app using `Rails 5.1.6` and `ruby 2.3.5p376`

I have these two gems in my `Gemfile`

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3.3'  
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 6.0.1'
```

In show.html.erb I have the following:

```
<script>
$( function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
} );
</script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

In application.js

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

In application.css

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

The browser now shows the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at application
```

If 'jquery-ui-rails' is removed from the app jquery function working fine.

Comment: Have you tried putting `//= require jquery` line on top of `//= require jquery-ui` and restart the server?

Comment: now working, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is your error here:

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery
```

Dependent scripts are included *in order*, i.e. when `jquery-ui` is loaded, it cannot find jQuery (which would get loaded next, but the script execution exits with your error and cannot continue).

To solve this, place `jquery` *before* `jquery-ui`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
```